# Read Text file and fill the data in Array.

Tags: android, text-files, filereader

Im pretty sure im just asking a silly question but, jut say in have a txt file that has this data on it

UniPub;112 Binara St;ACT
MooseHeads;54 Cohen St;ACT
Cube;24 Mawson St;ACT

Ill read it in my application using this code:

```
package au.edu.canberra.g30813706;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.os.Environment;


public class FileReader extends Activity{{

    ArrayList<String> sInfo = new ArrayList<String>();

    String txtName = "AccomodationTxt.txt";
    File root = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
    File path = new File(root, "CanberraTourism/" + txtName);

    try {

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader (
                            new InputStreamReader(
                            new FileInputStream(path)));
        String line;
        String[] saLineElements;
        while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
        {
            //The information is split into segments and stored into the array
            saLineElements = line.split(";");
            for (int i = 0; i < saLineElements.length; i++) 
                  sInfo.add(saLineElements[i]);
            //sInfo.addAll(Arrays.asList(saLineElements[0], saLineElements[1], saLineElements[3]));     
        }
         br.close();


    } 
    catch (FileNotFoundException e) {

        System.err.println("FileNotFoundException: " + e.getMessage());
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }}
}
```

How would i differentiate the lines in the Array?

For example

I would want to display the text of the names on one page, so only

UniPub
  MooseHeads
  Cube

Comment: Are you always going to have three values stored in the file in the format, `first_val;second_val;third_val`?

Comment: Does your code currently do any splitting to the string input?

Comment: why don't you store the lines in an array and when you need it you can split the lines and use the info? This way you'll have all the info separated for each line. Or is it necessary that you split at the beginning?

Comment: Its actually 5 values, there just an examples above

And i haven't tested it yet because i'm uncertain that it will work, thus this is why i asked this question

Answer (score 1):

What about adding the String arrays to the ArrayList instead of the individual elements.
Like this:

```
ArrayList<String[]> sInfo = new ArrayList<String[]>();
String line;
String[] saLineElements;
while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
{
    //The information is split into segments and stored into the array
    saLineElements = line.split(";");
        sInfo.add(saLineElements);
}
```

Then you could loop through sInfo and use the first element in each array in sInfo.