# How to Read from text file and Store into an Array in android

Tags: android, file, filereader, phone-number, stringbuffer

Hie Friends

I am developing an android application in that text file should be generated with some numbers. and after this one by one application should call to that numbers.

### For eg:

9876452125,
9876452135,
9876452115,

Mostly that text file have 8 numbers which is Separated by "," and New Line "\n"

Now I want to read From that file line by line.

**My Code for read file and store to array is:**

```
public void read(String fname)
    {
        BufferedReader br = null;
        try
        {
            StringBuffer output = new StringBuffer();
            String fpath = "/sdcard/" + fname + ".txt";
            br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fpath));
            String line = null;
            int index = 0;

            String[][] num = new String[15][10];

            List<String[]> collection = new ArrayList<String[]>();
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null)
            {
                if (index < num.length)
                {

                    output.append(line);
                    // output.append("\n");

                    num[index] = line.split(",");

                    if (num.length > 0)
                    {
                        collection.add(num[index]);
                    }
                }
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "" + collection, 5000)
                        .show();
                index++;

            }
        }
        catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

Now My problem is when I printing collection to Toast it display some random strings. I don't know why??

Does any one have proper idea or sample code for how to read from file line by line and store to Array.

Thanks allot.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Read Text file and fill the data in Array.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16338062/read-text-file-and-fill-the-data-in-array)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
   ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> myArray = new ArrayList<ArrayList<String>>();

    ArrayList<String> stringArray = new ArrayList<String>();
    String random = "9876452125, 9876452135, 9876452115,";

    String[] splitArray = random.split(",");

    for (int i = 0; i < splitArray.length; i++) {

        stringArray.add(splitArray[i]);
    }

    myArray.add(stringArray);

    // printing all values
    for (int i = 0; i < myArray.size(); i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < myArray.get(i).size(); j++) {

            System.out.println("values of index " + i + " are :"
                    + myArray.get(i).get(j));
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I was you I'd use a scanner. You haven't given information on how you plan to store them: for example, why you use  `String[][] num = new String[15][10];`, but I'll give you an example of if you wanted to store each number in it's own element, and you can adjust if necessary (I am assuming there is only one newline at the end of every line in your file).

```
public void read(String fname) {
    String fpath = "/sdcard/" + fname + ".txt";
    File file = new File(fpath); 
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new FileInputStream(file));
    List<String[]> collection = new ArrayList<String[]>();

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()){
    String line = scanner.nextLine();
            String.replaceAll("\n", ""); // strip the newline
            String[] myList = myString.split(",");
            for (i=0; i < myList.length; i++) {
                  collection.add(myList[i]);
            }       
    }
scanner.close();
}
```

This doesn't have any android elements in it, but like I said you can adjust as necessary to do what you specifically need it to do.

Comment: Android applications are written in Java, right? The above is Java. All that I didn't add is the Android Toast, because I am not sure what you are trying to show in the toast based on your code. Are you trying to make a toast show up for each number in your file?